# How to get one fields value with different colors based on another fields value in ssrs expression

Tags: reporting-services, expression

I have to color one field based on the value of another field.

Here is an example:

1. Textbox 10 should display field A.
2. The color of the text in Textbox 10 is based on the value of field B.

I see how I can change the color of Textbox 10 based on the value of field A, but I do not know how to have the color set based on the value of another field.

What is the code that I need to put into the SSRS expression for textbox 10?

Comment: You just need to use the other field name, As simple as that.

Comment: I tried that, and got the other value.  However I found that I can enter an expression on the color of the textbox in the properties, and can reference another field there.  Works great!

Answer (score 2):

You can reference any field that's in scope or that can be reached from your current scope. Use something like this for the color property of Textbox 10:

```
=IIF(Fields!FieldB.Value > 5, "#FF0000", "#00FF00")
```

Answer (score 0):

Enter the expression that references other fields, in the color property.